# Android databinding: unable to pass databinding variable to include layout

Tags: android, data-binding, include

i am having problem with databinding when binding a data to an include element in layout.xml It works on a Android 4.4.2 phone but when using on Android 4.3 phone the data not populate to the UI which layout file was referenced in the include tag.

Is it because the version of the phone? The document guide on google didn't seem to say anything about it.

Comment: I am using databinding and it's working fine on Galaxy S3 running 4.3, can you provide a minimum sample set up that will reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The phone version only plays a role in which attributes are supported. Some attributes are supported only in new APIs. For example, android:elevation only exists on API level 21 and above. If the API/attribute exists in 4.3 (version 18), then please file a bug in the public bug tracker so it can be fixed.